# Appending a value to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

Here is a mock-example of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have initially a list of empty lists of size 5:

```
l = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

Then, in a for loop that does 4 iterations, I have function that returns a list of indexes. I'd like to append "t" to the lists with those indexes.

Something like:

```
for t in range(4):
    idx = function_that_gives_indexes()
    l[idx].append(t)
```

Let's say that `function_that_gives_indexes()`, gives for each loop these value: `[1], [2, 4], [] and [0, 1]`. I'd like `l` to be:

```
l = [[3], [0, 3], [1], [], [1]]
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Since your function returns a list each time then your corrected code snippet is something like

```
for t in range(4):
    for idx in function_that_gives_indexes():
        l[idx].append(t)
```

And it does not look promising to try to make it more pythonic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear in the problem description, but that code snippet doesn't work it returns the error  
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list